# Calculations with comprehensions

Tags: coffeescript

Let's say I have the following:

```
scoringObject = 
  a : -1
  b : 0
  c : 1
  d : 2

resultsArray = ['a','c','b','b','c','c','d']
```

Using Coffescript, how can I calculate aggregateScore (+4 in the example) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your example doesn't make much sense as is, I'm going to assume that what you have is:

```
resultsArray = ['a','c','b','b','c','c','d']
```

with the `scoringObject` from your post. Then you could calculate like this:

```
aggregateScore = 0
aggregateScore += scoringObject[k] for k in resultsArray
# => 4
```

Let me know if I assumed wrongly.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using features from ECMAScript 5, [`Array::reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) lets you express this kind of thing quite succinctly:

```
aggregateScore = resultsArray.reduce ((sum, x) -> sum + scoringObject[x]), 0
```

(I feel that the parameter order of `reduce` is quite unfortunate; the initial value should be the first one, and the reducing function the last one)

Underscore.js [provides](http://underscorejs.org/#reduce) a cross-browser reduce implementation :)